# Integer as a product of a square and a square free integer

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers, integers

My question actually relates to an example given on p. 28 of Julian Havil's "Gamma".

Discussing a proof of the infinity of primes due to Erdos, Havil writes:

> [Erdos] uses a counting technique ... used by number theorists: that any integer can always be written as the product of a square and a square-free integer...

And then gives, as an example:

```
2851875 = 3^3 x 5^4 x 11 x 13^2 = 3 x 11 x (3 x 5^2 x 13)^2
```

But how can

```
(3 x 5^2 X 13)^2 = 3^2 x 5^4 x 13^2
```

?

**Oops** I should pay more attention - deleting this shortly, thanks for help in pointing out stupidity

**Further** Actually cannot delete as there is an answer so this monument to my inability to tell the difference between addition and multiplication will have to stay here!

Comment: oh I have been a bit of an idiot! Oh dear

Answer (score 2):

If an integer is already a perfect square, then $n^2=n^2\cdot 1$

Comment: But $1$ is not square-free. ;-)